# C# - How to create stack Id for caller?

Tags: c#, task, callstack

I want to make Caller Id for method calling, what is that? CallerID is identify of calling a method like Task.CurrentId but in this case I don't want to create new thread to access ThreadId,
For Example:

```
    public class OperationMethodContext
{
    public static OperationMethodContext Current { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MethodName { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OperationMethodContext.Current = new OperationMethodContext() {  Guid = Guid.NewGuid(), MethodName="call 1", Id = 1};
        MethodRun();
        OperationMethodContext.Current = new OperationMethodContext() {  Guid = Guid.NewGuid(), MethodName="call 2", Id = 2};
        MethodRun();
        OperationMethodContext.Current = new OperationMethodContext() {  Guid = Guid.NewGuid(), MethodName="call 3", Id = 3};
        MethodRun();
        OperationMethodContext.Current = new OperationMethodContext() {  Guid = Guid.NewGuid(), MethodName="call 4", Id = 4};
        MethodRun();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static async void MethodRun()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("call started: " + OperationMethodContext.Current.MethodName);
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("call finished: " + OperationMethodContext.Current.MethodName);
    }
}
```

I want to get OperationMethodContext.Current per method calling without send OperationMethodContext as parameters or properties, if I had to more call stacks i want to access OperationMethodContext.Current per stack calling.

Comment: You known about [CallerMemberNameAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: those attributes are static, i think i need a value like guid that is diiferent by call